# How to make my page title responsive with CSS?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make the header of my page responsive (I first code for mobile and after going to wider viewports) and I am using this HTML and CSS codes:

HTML:

```
     <header>



        <div class="page_title">
            <h1 >TOYWAWA</h1>
        </div>


        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="nou.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
       </nav>
    </header>
```

and CSS:

```
    header {
                   width: 100%;
                   border-bottom: 10px solid black;
                   border-top: 10px solid black;
                   height: 300px;
                   background-image: url(back.2.jpg)
           }


        .page_title {
                 max-width: 100%;
                 margin-top: 75px;
                 margin-bottom: 50px;
                 font-size: 70px;
                 font-family: BrandonGrotesque-Black, "futura-pt-1","futura-pt-2", Verdana, sans-serif;
                 }



        nav ul li {

             display: inline-block;
             padding: 15px;
             list-style-type: none;
             font-family: BrandonGrotesque-Black, "futura-pt-1","futura-pt-2", Verdana, sans-serif;

                }
```

This is a link with a complete fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Cilvako/5Lcy4cxx/embedded/result/

For some reason the fiddle doesn't display the exact same thing I get in a browser - in the browser the navigation menu under the page title doesn't go out from the containing div, it gets displayed right under the title. This is how the website will look at 320 px and I am testing in with Responsive Design View Tool. At this resolutin, the page title gets cut off. The same thing happens with the backgroung image. I gave the div that contains the page title a max-width of 100% but still didn't helped. Any ideas?

Comment: May be you need use **@media queries**

Comment: if it is about font-size, then vw and vh units could be usefull, at least for smartphone and tablets i believe: https://jsfiddle.net/5Lcy4cxx/2/ - https://jsfiddle.net/5Lcy4cxx/2/embedded/result/

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #000;
    border-top: 10px solid #000;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url("back.2.jpg");
}
.page_title {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 70px;
    font-family: BrandonGrotesque-black,"futura-pt-1","futura-pt-2",Verdana,sans-serif;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) { 
/* Styles for screen with max width of 600px */
    header {
        height: auto;
    }
    .page_title {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 25px;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 320px) { 
/* Styles for screen with max width of 320px */
    header {
        height: auto;
    }
    .page_title {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but the background image doesn't resize. And with the header's height set to auto, the header just looks very weird.

Comment: Media queries are probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove the div for .page_title and change the class for `<h1>` tag to .page_title.

```
<h1 class="page_title"></h1>
```

The css will then apply to the heading, not the container.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/5Lcy4cxx/3/

Comment: Is there a way to make the title appear uncut withouth making the font smaller? I made it that big for a reson. As i said, when I test my code in a browser, the navigation menu fits in the containing div, I don't know why fiddle displays it that way. So my main issues is that I want the background image and page title to be displayed at 100% size.

Comment: add the media queries and viewport without adjusting the pixels for font-size

Comment: Well, this is my issue, the code that I need to add in the media query - or maybe I am not asking the correct question. I do not understand why the container and its content is responsive without any media queries and the header isn't (I am talking about the h1 and the backgroung image)? It's because of the font size? Forget about the fact I want to make it responsive, let's say that my website will only be made for a phone with 320px resolution. Why all of my elements flow nicely but the header?

Comment: This is how originally my code looked like, Still nothing. And it's very frustrating because everything on the page is resizing (re-aranging) except for the background image and the h1.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5Lcy4cxx/6/, i've added margin:auto; to your header and main_container and overflow:auto to your main container